# Get values out of a Series in Python

Tags: python, numpy, series

I have the following Series in Python, and would like to obtain the LSOA11CD values which align with 'True':

```
LSOA11CD
E01006512    False
E01006513    True
E01006514    False
E01006515    False
E01006518    True
E01006519    False
E01006520    False
E01006521    False
E01006522    True
E01006523    False
E01006524    False
E01006525    True
```

I am using the following code to obtain these, but I only get four returns of 'True' rather than four returns of LSOA codes:

```
for LSOA11CD in IMD.centroid.within(SchoolsBuffer[10]):
    if LSOA11CD == True:
        print LSOA11CD.index
```

The data type of the series is simply a numpy bool series.

Comment: Sorry are you after `LSOA11CD[LSOA11CD == True]` or `LSOA11CD[LSOA11CD == True].index`?

Comment: I'm assuming the index is what I'm after?.. if E01006513 is the index of the first True then yes

Comment: ..but it doesn't appear to have an index within the data structure - when I call .index it throws out an error

Comment: Is this pandas series?

Comment: I think it's numpy - this is the error: 

AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'index'